# deploy ear file to weblogic 10g

Tags: java, weblogic, ear

I have coded project in java ee. by using java ee version 6. when I try to deploy my ear file into weblogic 10g I receive the following error:

How can I achieve it? How can I correctly deploy the file?

> Unable to access the selected application.
>       Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
>       Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
>       [J2EE:160161]Error while parsing the Application descriptors for 1BB.ear: 
>       weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed at 
>       weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:152) at 
>       weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:306) at 
>       weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788) at 
>       weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:409) at 
>       weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759) at 
>       weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768) at 
>       weblogic.application.ApplicationDescriptor.getWeblogicApplicationDescriptor(ApplicationDescriptor.java:339) at 
>       weblogic.application.compiler.CompilerCtx.setApplicationDescriptor(CompilerCtx.java:139) at weblogic.application.compiler.AppcUtils.setDDs(AppcUtils.java:142) at 
>       weblogic.application.compiler.flow.DescriptorParsingFlow.compile(DescriptorParsingFlow.java:57) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:69) 
>       at 
>       weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:36) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$CompilerFlowDriver.compile(FlowDriver.java:96)
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.ReadOnlyEarMerger.merge(ReadOnlyEarMerger.java:49) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:94) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:47) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:69) 
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:36) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$CompilerFlowDriver.compile(FlowDriver.java:96) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:157) 
>       at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158) 
>       at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115) 
>       at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:169) 
>       at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:88) 
>       at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:63) 
>       at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:181) 
>       at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createLazyDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:156) 
>       at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.inspect(SessionHelper.java:661) 
>       at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow$2.execute(Flow.java:463) 
>       at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:4625) 
>       at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow.appSelected(Flow.java:461) 
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1036.invoke(Unknown Source) 
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52) 
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116) 
>       at com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:255) 
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158) 
>       at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:256) 
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) 
>       at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:133) 
>       at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199) 
>       at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:686) 
>       at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:142) 
>       at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:106) 
>       at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:388) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:199) 
>       at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:251) 
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) 
>       at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:54) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:130) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3496) 
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) 
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086) 
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406) 
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201) 
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173) 
>       Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to e=weblogic-application@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application 
>       at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.getPojoBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:361) 
>       at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:316) 
>       at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:326) 
>       at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineRootType(UnmarshalResult.java:307) 
>       at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:158) 
>       at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:65) 
>       at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:141) ... 119 more .

here is my weblogic-application.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd"/>
```

Comment: your EAR has a file at `META-INF/weblogic-application.xml` - Check if that file matches what it should look like as per the schema http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/app_xml.html#wp1064995 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/app_xml.html#wp1079285

Comment: I have added my current weblogic-application.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try add 3 files to EAR:

1) **META-INF\application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <display-name>My App</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>appEJB.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>app.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>app</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

2) **META-INF\weblogic-application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <!--weblogic-version:10.3.2-->
    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

3) **META-INF\MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: 
Weblogic-Application-Version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is possible in two cases,

1. web.xml file is corrupted
2. Any configuration missing in the web.xml file.
3. web-app tag may not correctly defined it depends on your project.

In my case the error cause by first point.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping web.xml @ WebContent instead of WEB-INF(if in case). That solved my issue.

Comment: What is  @ WebContent....? a folder i guess? Been accurate can help other better to understand. Thanks!